# How to generate class with const or non-const member function from a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a following template:

```
template<typename Signature>
class TypeErasedFunctor;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class TypeErasedFunctor<R(Args...)>
{
public:

    virtual R operator()(Args... args) = 0;
};
```

It can be used to generate interface classes for functors like this:

`using SemaphoreFunctor = TypeErasedFunctor<int(Semaphore&)>;`

As can be seen the member function `operator()` is non-const. I'd like to ask the following question - are there any options to select whether const or non-const variant should be created other than these two:

- using SFINAE (possibly with `std::enable_if<>`) and additional argument for template,
- using a separate template `ConstTypeErasedFunctor`

Comment: For this particular problem, just make it `const`, because, by convention, functors are expected to be stateless, and therefore, immutable / const. That's what `std::function` does. You can always circumvent the constness in the derived class by holding the non-const functor as a `mutable` data member.

Comment: @MikaelPersson - Well, with the part about being "stateless" I cannot agree (if functors should be stateless, what's the gain compared to a plain function?), but could you elaborate more about "holding the non-const functor as a mutable data member"? I must admit that the motivation for question is the need to modify the contents of the object derived from this template (on some occasions), not the use of `operator() const` on non-const objects.

Comment: Stateless is meant in the sense that any two consequent calls to the function will have the same effect and result. Typically, functors are passed over as callbacks or as auxiliaries to algorithms (e.g., predicates, comparison function, etc.), in which it is undefined how often and when exactly the functor will be invoked, and in that context, it is much preferable if it's stateless. However, stateless does not mean "parameter-less", and that's where functors (callable obj) are better than function pointers. Usually, you need a *parametrized* functor, not a *stateful* functor.

Comment: As for elaborating on "holding the non-const functor as a mutable data member"... I don't how much I could elaborate, it's pretty clear. If you have to modify, on occasions, a few of the data members of a particular derived class within the `operator()`, then you can just use `mutable` in those rare cases. If the problem is that you don't know about the mutable keyword, just read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2h0ktk.aspx).

Comment: @MikaelPersson - I understand now. Previously I thought you meant I could have objects derived from the base class kept as mutable members of other objects, which didn't make much sense (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have both (const and no const) versions of operator () on the same object as overloads. But if you want to easily select only one when declaring the object, you can use something like that:

```
template<bool b, typename Signature>
class TypeErasedFunctor;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class TypeErasedFunctor<true,R(Args...)>
{
    public:
        virtual R operator() (Args... args) const = 0;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class TypeErasedFunctor<false,R(Args...)>
{
    public:
        virtual R operator()(Args... args) = 0;
};

template<bool b>
using SemaphoreFunctor = TypeErasedFunctor<b,int(Semaphore&)>;
```

Later, in client code, you can choose with the remaining generic argument:

```
SemaphoreFunctor<true> object_with_const_op;
SemaphoreFunctor<false> object_with_no_const_op;
```